# Loading dropdownlists

Tags: wpf, vb.net, lookup-tables

what is the best way to load dropdown lists from reference/lookup tables for a desktop application?

the application is layed out into 3 tiers. I've built up my entities.

the front end has a form with 6 tabs. and one big save (another discussion :)

Should I load them all when the form is initially loaded? Are there any caching mechanisms I could use?

it is vb.net app on a network drive that is accessed by several users.

it's also worth noting that some reference tables may be updated. Via another form.

thanks
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of factors.  One you need to populate in constructor so the data is there to populate the visual elements.  Beware that just because a tab is not visible does not mean it is not loaded when you app starts.

For a static list of strings

```
    public class Library : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<string>  dropDown1;

        public List<string> DropDown1 { get { return dropDown1; } } 

        public Library()
        {
            // use data reader to populate dropDown1
        }
    }
```

I know this will get comments that can use something lighter than a List but List has a lot of nice features, easy syntax, and easy to populate.  As a next step you could structure as  a client server and use some static so the list is populated once and then shared by all.  If you have more properties then substitute string with a class.  For a dynamic list then in the get you grab the current data from the table on demand.  In your get you could hold on to the last list and if the next request is within X seconds then return stale data.  It depends on if stale data is acceptable.

There are many other approaches and I do not pretend this is the best.  Just putting out a relatively simple example to get you started.

When it gets to hierarchical then things get a little more complex.  There you can use ADO.NET table to store the static dependent data and then apply a filter on a view.

Comment: thanks BB. I'm going to load them all up at startup. After a couple of tweaks to the combobox in WPF, they load very quickly and with multiple columns in some cases(which btw is a nice feature)

Comment: @TeddyRuxpin Could you mark is as an answer since you are going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If its a web page you don't have to load all tabs on page load.
Desktop i think it will be more easy and it should be like that.

Only when the user click on the tab show the page and hide all the pages
associated for other tabs.

i  hope all tab pages values will be on session so that user can go and come back to any tab and your Big Save at last.

Something useful related to your  question i found  here

http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/windowsforms/faq_c93c.aspx

and [one more](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0260__GUI/0740__TabControl.htm)

Comment: The tag is wpf.  Pretty sure this in not an aspx application.  If this is an aspx question the it needs to get re-tagged.

Comment: it's not an aspx. as I mentioned it's a desktop application.